# Scrapy Amazon absolute path but with no value returned

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to use Scrapy some info from amazon.co.uk by using absolute path as below. but strangely no value returned. I am quite new to Scrapy:

```
scrapy shell http://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/B0042EU3A2/

response.xpath('//*[@id="productReviews"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[1]/@name').extract()
```

I would like it to return name attribute in this case is: `RI4HGFJCSI04W`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit the `tbody` from the expression:

```
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@id="productReviews"]//tr/td[1]/a[1]/@name').extract()
Out[1]: [u'RI4HGFJCSI04W']
```

Comment: Thanks! but why "tbody" causing troubles?

Comment: @W.S. the problem is that `tbody` element doesn't exist in the HTML source for that page. You probably saw it in the browser DOM, but that's because the browser creates a `tbody` element automatically for all tables.